# How to efficiently update a value in a table with 2.5 million records

Tags: sql

How can I append a value (Eg: apple) to 2.5 million records in a database. How can I do it in an efficient way?

Example Table:

| left | center | right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three |
| Four | Five | Six |
| Four |  | Six |

Expected Output:

| left | center | right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two, apple | Three |
| Four | Five, apple | Six |
| Four | apple | Six |

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: `update foo set center = center + [', apple' | 'apple'] where center is [not] null;` ?

Comment: if you need to update all rows, than you need time to do it, you only can split the number of rows that will be updated at a time, to reduce down time due to overload, that is why you need a maintenance plan ready before hand